# Google App Engine Datastore sharding in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, sharding

I have made a shard in GAE and only sometimes, not always got this message after running the sharding code.

```
(datastore_v3: BAD_REQUEST): Key path element must not be incomplete: [ResumeShard: ]
```

The code:

```
//Sharding
//Getting shard ID
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
shardId := rand.Int63n(5)
resumeShardKey := datastore.NewKey(*pC, "ResumeShard", "", accountKey.IntID()+shardId, nil)

var resumeShard param.ResumeShard

if err = datastore.Get(*pC, resumeShardKey, &resumeShard); err != nil {

    if err == datastore.ErrNoSuchEntity {
        resumeShard = param.ResumeShard{}
        resumeShard.Counter = 1
    } else {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }

} else {
    resumeShard.Counter += 1
}
```

`*pC` is a pointer to the context from appengine.

`accountKey` is a datastore `Key` unique to each user.

This error shows up randomly, like 3 times in 10 requests. I am wondering because I have to use `datastore.NewKey(..)` to create keys for shards, how can I get the complete key that I will receive after calling `Put(..)` since this is sharding and the example on GAE doc uses `datastore.NewKey(..)` as well.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an error stating that the key you provide is incomplete. This is because you specify an empty key name (`""`) (`stringID`), and `accountKey.IntID()` plus a random number (from the range `0..4` - both inclusive) as the numeric key ID (`intID`). Note that if your `accountKey.IntID()` is not initialized, it will be `0` and the random number may also be `0` in which case a `0` is used as the `intID`.

And quoting from the doc of [`datastore.Key`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#NewKey):

> Either one or both of `stringID` and `intID` must be zero. If both are zero, the key returned is incomplete.

The chance of getting `0` for the `intID` is 1 out of 5 which is 20% (this is close to your reported 3 out of 10).

A value of `0` for `intID` is invalid, it has to be a non-zero value as `0` is a special value just like the empty string `""` for the `stringID`, both which are used to indicate that the other property is used to identify the entity; or - if both are the zero value - to indicate that the key is an incomplete key (and so system assigned random `intID` is wanted).

Please note that this solution is bad as you use keys with *relative* numeric ID (`intID`), relative compared to the numeric ID of the account key (`accountKey.IntID()`). System-assigned keys will be randomly distributed, but there is a chance that 2 account keys may be close to each other (e.g. one is the other +1). In such case your shard keys would overlap!

If you use [`datastore.Put()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#NewKey) to save an entity, the system assigned random key is the return value of `Put()`:

```
func Put(c context.Context, key *Key, src interface{}) (*Key, error)
```

Comment: You are really an expert! Thank you so much for your help!